# Understanding builds for Watch-iPhone app in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos, watchapp, watchos-simulator

I have an iPhone app with an Apple extension and when I build the app in XCode only the Watch app starts building, I see both simulators but the iPhone app doesn't launch, is this a normal behavior when testing iPhone+Watch app?

I would like to have more control as far as builds since at times I just want to test the iPhone app and the Watch app doesn't need to be involved and vice versa.

1. Can I have both apps launch when building in Xcode so I can debug both?
2. Can I stop testing the watch app and only test the iPhone app if I wanted to?
3. Is there a way to speedup the build time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Watch App's or Watch Extension's scheme is selected, when you press Build, only your Watch app will launch.

You can launch both separately and debug both. If you only want to test the iPhone app, you can do it exactly as usual by selecting the iPhone app and running it from Xcode.

Regarding the build time, I think it's as fast as possible. Just make sure you don't have something that causes a full rebuild each time you are debugging, as build usually takes less than 2 seconds when working on a project if the project is not building from ground up (which usually takes over a minute in a normal-sized project).

Comment: @ Can Poyrazoğlu Thanks, quick question. `Just make sure you don't have something that causes a full rebuild` What would cause a full rebuild and what doesn't? I usually make my changes and just hit the Run button.

Comment: @fs_tigre I can't think of anything in particular but something that changes build configuration (an extension or a script that is triggered at build, perhaps?) might cause it. A plain Xcode installation with a regular project shouldn't cause that behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!